# How i create this textview style?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I try to create this textview style, my problem is that :

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:text="HOLLIDAY"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
            />
```

MY OUTPUT IS THIS :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfLbk.png)

AND I WANT THIS :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap3Ja.png)

Comment: I think You have to write a string with \n afte every letters.

Comment: @BhargavThanki this string can be change by user, so this is not a good solution... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom text view for this

```
private const val VERTICAL_ROTATION = 270f

class VerticalTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0) :
  AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyle) {

  private var _measuredWidth: Int = 0
  private var _measuredHeight: Int = 0
  private val _bounds = Rect()

  override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    _measuredHeight = measuredWidth
    _measuredWidth = measuredHeight
    setMeasuredDimension(_measuredWidth, _measuredHeight)
  }

  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    canvas.save()

    canvas.translate(_measuredWidth.toFloat(), _measuredHeight.toFloat())
    canvas.rotate(VERTICAL_ROTATION)

    val textPaint = paint
    textPaint.color = currentTextColor

    val text = getViewText()

    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, _bounds)
    canvas.drawText(text, compoundPaddingLeft.toFloat(), ((_bounds.height() - _measuredWidth) / 2).toFloat(), textPaint)

    canvas.restore()
  }

  private fun getViewText(): String = super.getText().toString()
}
```

Comment: oh... need code... Thanks for the answer friend! We haven't solution on xml ?

Comment: don't know u can try

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack if you want to do it with XML.

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:text="H\nO\nL\nI\nD\nA\nY"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
        />
```